# What is AWS Kinesis AT_TIMESTAMP format for Timestamp in REST API?

Tags: amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to get an AT_TIMESTAMP shard iterator from a Stream. I am calling the REST API and passing the exact timestamp examples from the AWS documentation with no luck. I've also tried several other variations.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_GetShardIterator.html#Streams-GetShardIterator-request-ShardIteratorType

Attempts so far include both documented values and System.currentTimeMillis(), among others.

Examples:

```
"2016-04-04T19:58:46.480-00:00"
"1459799926.480"
"16035057631"
```

ERROR:

```
{
  "__type": "SerializationException",
  "Message": "class java.lang.String can not be converted to milliseconds since epoch"
}
```

The Postman set up is:

```
POST https://kinesis.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=GetShardIterator

Headers:

Authorization:<MY AUTH INFO HERE>
Content-Type:application/x-amz-json-1.1
X-Amz-Target:Kinesis_20131202.GetShardIterator

Body:

{
    "ShardId": "shard-000000000000",
    "ShardIteratorType": "AT_TIMESTAMP",
    "Timestamp": "16035057631",
    "StreamName": "MyStreamNameHere"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

aws kinesis get-shard-iterator --stream-name $name --shard-id shardId-000000000000 --shard-iterator-type AT_TIMESTAMP --timestamp 1634808046

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).